# How to create a drill down table

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a drill down table based on what the user wants to display. I am having problems with the tidy evaluation of the user's choice from a drop down box and as a result the drill down table doesn't show the relevant results.

The code is here:

```
library("shiny")
library("DT")



ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("endoDoc_documentqual"),
  dataTableOutput("summary")

  , dataTableOutput("drilldown")
)


server <- function(input, output){


  output$endoDoc_documentqual<-renderUI({
    selectInput("endoDoc_documentqualChoose", label = h4("Choose teh column of interest"),
                choices = colnames(iris) ,selected = 1
    )
  })

  # display the data that is available to be drilled down
  output$summary <- DT::renderDataTable(# create a summary table

    summary_iris <- group_by(iris, !!rlang::sym(input$endoDoc_documentqualChoose)) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(Count = n())

  )

  # subset the records to the row that was clicked
  drilldata <- reactive({
    shiny::validate(
      need(length(input$summary_rows_selected) > 0, "Select rows to drill down!")
    )    

   selected_species <- summary_iris[as.integer(input$summary_rows_selected), ]$Species
    iris[iris$Species %in% selected_species, ]
  })

  # display the subsetted data
  output$drilldown <- DT::renderDataTable(drilldata())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<<-` instead of `<-` while assigning the `summary_iris`

```
    summary_iris <<- group_by(iris, !!rlang::sym(input$endoDoc_documentqualChoose)) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Count = n())
```

But at the bottom there is another problem as well. You choose only the `$Species` column. However, it is only available for the Species input inside the `selectInput`.

UPDATE:

If I don't understand you wrongly, those codes give the `iris` output wrt the user selection.

```
selected_species <- summary_iris[as.integer(input$summary_rows_selected), ]
variables <-    c(t(selected_species[,1]))
mycolname <- colnames(selected_species)[1]
iris[iris[, mycolname] %in%  variables ,]
```

Comment: Thanks @maydin. So how do I change these lines so that it can take the user input:  selected_species <- summary_iris[as.integer(input$summary_rows_selected), ]$Species
    iris[iris$Species %in% selected_species, ]

Comment: @Sebastian Zeki I am so sorry but I did not understand you clearly. Do you just want to get  what has been selected inside the data table at the top for showing them in the drill down table ? Or something else ?

Comment: Hi @maydin I want the user to be able to select the column to be able to choose the column (with the count) as the primary datatable and then to be able to select a row that shows all the values in the iris set that have the same value in the user selected column. Eg if the user selects Petal.Width the primary table shows this column with a count and then if the row with 2,4 is chosen the drill down shows all rows from the original iris set with Petal.Width 2.4